# Django - form validate images on upload

Tags: python, django

How to clean() an image with his size and extension? Image is uploading well into db, but when i'm trying to get cleaned_data it returns None.

I set same looking validator on models and it works well, but only when i upload an image by adminsite.

forms.py:

```
class AdditionalInfoForm(forms.Form):
first_name = forms.CharField(label='First name', max_length=20)
last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last name', max_length=40)
male = forms.ChoiceField(label="Male", choices=MALES, required=False)
date_of_birth = forms.DateTimeField(label="Date of birth", required=False, widget=DateInput)
about = forms.CharField(label='Tell us about yourself', widget=forms.Textarea(), required=False)
image = forms.ImageField(label="Profile picture", required=False)

def clean_image(self):
    avaible_formats = [
        'png',
        'jpeg',
        'jpg',
        ]
    img = self.cleaned_data.get('image')
    print(img) #always None
    if img:
        img_ext = img.name.split(".")[-1]
        if img.size > 4194304:
            raise ValidationError("Image size must be less than 4MB")
        if img_ext not in avaible_formats:
            raise ValidationError("Image extension is not avaible")        
    return img
```

views.py:

```
def account_settings(request):
user = request.user
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = AdditionalInfoForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        user.first_name = cd['first_name']
        user.last_name = cd['last_name']
        profile.date_of_birth = cd['date_of_birth']
        profile.male = cd['male']
        profile.about = cd['about']
        img = request.FILES.get("image")
        if img is not None:
            profile.profile_picture = img
        user.save()
        profile.save()
        return redirect(reverse('user_data:details'))
else:
    form = AdditionalInfoForm(initial={
        "first_name": user.first_name,
        "last_name": user.last_name,
        "date_of_birth": profile.date_of_birth,
        "male": profile.male,
        "about": profile.about
    })
return render(request, 'social/settings.html', {"form": form})
```

template:

```
<p>Make some changes as you wish</p>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}
<input type="submit" value="Apply">       
</form>
```

models.py

```
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default='images/default.png', validators=[validate_image])
```

validate_image:

```
def validate_image(img):
    size = img.size
    format = img.name.split(".")[-1]
    avaible_formats = [
        'png',
        'jpeg',
        'jpg',
    ]
    if size > 4194304:
        raise ValidationError("Image size must be less than 4MB")
    if format not in avaible_formats:
        raise ValidationError("Image extension is not avaible")
    
    return img
```

Comment: Can you provide the django template, where you are using the form and the corresponding view in your question?

Comment: For start you have to also include request.FILES in `form = AdditionalInfoForm(request.POST)`. There is doc for it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads

Comment: OK, added request.FILES to form works. Thanks!